# Simplify typescript coding workflow

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In our project we are using AngularJs (v1) with typescript and I found our workflow a bit too complex and slow. That's why I would like to ask the stackoverflow community about how I can simplify this.

---

1) Manually update _references.ts
Right now we maintain by hand the file _references.ts. Everytime that we need to add/remove a file, we need to update this file with the right order. I would like to know if there isn't a solution to auto generate this file. In the properties of my typescript project, I have in Output section an option "Generate declaration files" but it seems that is not the right option...

---

2) Role of intensive use of interface 
I saw on many typescript tutorial wth angularJs that we need in every file to have the following 3 elements:

```
   interface ISplashScreenController {}
   interface ISplashScreenControllerScope extends ng.IScope {}
   class SplashScreenController implements ISplashScreenController {}
```

I can easily understand for the scope (to set vm as the type of SplashScreenController in this sample), but the global interface is it really useful ? What's the reason to use interface here instead just declaring SplashscreenController ?

---

3) Global injection

I would like to be able to inject some global services. For example : $translate, $q, $timeout, moment, my own CommonServices... Indeed, many controller/services in my app use this, and is a bit weird to inject it everytime that I need it. I would like to be able to use this everywhere.

This is especially true that for example I would like to have a "DateFormatTools" and be able to use it directly in my html without needed to inject it in my controller and then call vm.DateFormatTools.format(...)

---

4) One of the biggest issue is to maintain both app.ts and $inject and the injection in the constructor. Here is a sample :

in app.ts:

```
smartLingoApp.controller("SplashScreenController", ["$scope", "$q", "$timeout", "$translate", "DialogServices", "InitializationServices", "LocalStorageServices", "UserServices", "StateStackServices", SplashScreenController]);
```

in splashScreenController.ts:

```
static $inject = ["$scope", "$q", "$timeout", "$translate", "DialogServices", "InitializationServices", "LocalStorageServices", "UserServices", "StateStackServices"];
constructor($scope: ISplashScreenControllerScope,
    private $q: angular.IQService,
    private $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
    private $translate: angular.translate.ITranslateService,
    private dialogServices: IDialogServices,
    private initializationServices: IInitializationServices,
    private localStorageServices: ILocalStorageServices,
    private userServices: IUserServices,
    private stateStackServices: IStateStackServices) {}
```

and of course everytime I add/remove a dependency I need to update both $inject and both app.ts which can create mistake. 
Ideally, it will be nice to set the dependency only in the splashScreenController.ts

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

> Manually update _references.ts Right now we maintain by hand the file _references.ts. Everytime that we need to add/remove a file, we need to update this file with the right order. I would like to know if there isn't a solution to auto generate this fil

Long ago... I wrote this for `grunt` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/#reference

Which maintains `reference.ts` for you.

## More

Video: https://youtu.be/0-6vT7xgE4Y

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand why but my app.ts is included at the top of the generate _references files, and of course app.ts need other typescript defs so my app crash.